# empty linked repository in bamboo

Tags: rest, bamboo

I configured a linked repository from the Bamboo header select Administration > Build resources > Linked repositories.

Although I looked for "GET /rest/api/latest/repository" API, it returned an empty repository list.

Is there a way to get a linked repository via the REST API?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try setting the `searchTerm` param to some value?

Comment: Yes. I gave the repos ID as a value of the searchTerm, but the result is the same. It was empty

Comment: Try with repo name instead of its ID.

Comment: When I requested with repo name, it gave me a link as a response.
The link is a UI url that can edit a linked repository.